# Where in Wordpress Admin can I find this list of links?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On this [jewellery website](http://www.lajewellery.co.uk/product-category/fair-trade-silver/) there are links at the top HOME / JEWELLERY / COLLECTIONS. Some of the items (Necklaces, Earrings, etc) appear in the small vertical list on the left too. I am unable to find where in the admin screens I need to go in order to find this list and add new items.

It uses Woo Commerce and WordPress.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: It looks like a widget in a sidebar. So perhaps try - Appearance > Widgets and in here look for a WooCommerce sidebar or any sidebar that might have a widget producing this list

Comment: Thanks. I've looked through all of the widgets but they only contains "terms and conditions" and stuff like that, nothing in relation to this content. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you could go check in plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php and see where the sidebar is coming from.  Or if your theme has made any custom changes to woocommerce it will be in themes/your_theme_name/woocommerce/content-single-product.php

Comment: Apologies, I didn't look at the page you were on correctly.  Replace content-single-product.php with product-archive.php or if any customisations have been made taxonomy-product_cat.php